# How to put multiple inherited entities in a single table?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-data

I have four classes which should put in one db table.

First class represents basic information.

```
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "TYPE")
@Entity
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY)
public class A {

  @Id
  private String id;

  private LocalDateTime date;
  private String someString;
}
```

The second class extends class a and has some extra properties.

```
@Inheritance
@MappedSuperclass
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY)
public class B extends A {

  private String extraProperty;
}
```

Finally there are two parallel classes with concrete type information.

```
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue(value = "C1")
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY)
public class C1 extends B {

  private String property1;
  private String property2;
}


@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue(value = "C2")
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY)
public class C2 extends B {

  private String propertyX;
  private String propertyY;
}
```

The ReST repository looks like this:

```
@RepositoryRestResource(
        path = "items",
        collectionResourceRel = "items"
)
public interface ItemRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<A, String> { }
```

Now I have written a test where the expected format is tested.

```
@Test
public void shouldReturnItemlistWithCorrectDataStructure() throws Exception {    
        mockMvc.perform(get("/Items"))
               .andExpect(jsonPath("$._embedded.items").isArray())
               .andExpect(jsonPath("$._embedded.items", hasSize(2)))

               .andExpect(jsonPath("$._embedded.items[0].id").value("1234567"))
               ...
    }
```

I expected one array (items[]) in the result json but there are actually two different arrays c1[] and c2[].

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Did you try to make your class A and B abstract ?

Comment: Yes I tried this, but there are no changes in the result.